# NSPredicateEditor not handling integer values

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspredicateeditor

I have a fairly simple `NSPredicateEditor` setup, and any String based predicates work fine, but integer predicates are causing an exception.

The predicate editor appears to be configured correctly…

[image]

…but whenever I choose one of those left hand values from the predicate editor, I get this exception, like the predicate editor is treating the number as a string:

`2016-10-29 10:48:12.416 PredicateBarTesting[29041:303] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x37
2016-10-29 10:48:12.419 PredicateBarTesting[29041:303] An uncaught exception was raised`

Full exception: http://d.pr/n/XT97

Any ideas?

Source code: http://d.pr/f/Ng2l

Comment: Are `level`, `ownerPID` and/or `windowID` string properties?

Comment: @Willeke No, they are all forms of integers (int32_t, pid_t, and uint32_t, respectively).

Comment: The exception is in `-[NSString compare:options:range:]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left expressions in the predicate editor row template shoud be 'Keypaths' instead of 'Contant Values' (strings).

Comment: Good catch.  That might indeed be the fix, but it appears I'm running into an Xcode bug where Keypaths are being turned into a Constant Values.  And any time I try to change it back, Xcode clears the list.  Checkout the video: http://d.pr/v/cayf

Comment: Close and open the project and try again.

Comment: SOLUTION: I eventually just had to edit the XIB file by hand.  Restarting Xcode and cleaning caches didn't help, and any time I touch that NSPredicateTemplate's settings in IB, they revert to Constant Values.